# Given $T^2 = T$ find all eigenvalues of $T$...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a linear operator $T$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, satisfying $T^2 = T$ answer the following:

(a) Using the dimension theorem, show that $N(T) \bigoplus R(T) = V$;

(b) Identify all eigenvalues of $T$ and the corresponding eigenspaces and show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

I have already proven part (a). Basically define $Tv = w$ and the rest follows.

Part (b) however I am honestly confused on where to start.

Comment: Hint: how are the eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^2$ related?

Comment: I know that they must be the same. Since our vector space is finite-dimensional, then we are guaranteed the existence of an eigenvalue. That is, there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$. Since $T^2 = T$, we then have that $T^2v = \lambda v$. It then follows that $T(Tv) = \lambda Tv = \lambda^2 v = \lambda v$. Therefore, any eigenvalue of $T$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 = \lambda$, so our eigenvalues are 0 and 1. Is this correct? But then I am confused again...wouldn't this mean that we do not have a basis of eigenvectors, therefore, it is not diagonalizable?

Comment: Hint: what are the possible minimal polynomials given that $T^2-T=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition:
$$Tv = \lambda v$$
Multiply both sides by $T$:
$$T^2 v = \lambda T v.$$ 
Recall that $T^2 = T$:
$$Tv = \lambda Tv.$$
Since $Tv = \lambda v$, then:
$$\lambda v = \lambda \cdot \lambda v = \lambda^2 v.$$
That is:

$$\lambda = \lambda^2.$$

This equation has only two solutions: $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$.

For $\lambda = 0$, the eigenspace corresponds to the null space of $T$.
For $\lambda = 1$, the eigenspace is given by all vectors $v$ such that:

$$(T-I)v = 0,$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Funny, I just commented this on the response above. Oh, I get it now. These are the ONLY eigenvalues, therefore it is diagonalizable!

Comment: The eigenspace for the unit eigenvalues is actually the range of $T$, since if $\boldsymbol v\in V$, then $T (T\boldsymbol v) =1\cdot (T\boldsymbol v)$, so $T\boldsymbol v$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: To be precise, $0$ and $1$ are the potential eigenvalues. The operator $T$ can have $0$ as the unique eigenvalue, in which case $T-1$ is invertible and from the equation you get $T=0$. It can also have $1$ as the unique eigenvalue in which case $T$ is invertible and $T=1$.

Comment: @mouthetics I did not say that both $0$ and $1$ are eigenvalues of $T$. I just said that they are solutions of $\lambda = \lambda^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. If $v$ is an eigenvector, then $\lambda v=Tv=T^2v=\lambda^2v$, so $\lambda=\lambda^2$.
2. $R(T)$ coincides with the eigenspace of $\lambda=1$, then use part (a).